# sas sgplot text at various position

Tags: graph, sas

In sgplot, use `inset` statement can insert a text box inside graph.

```
proc sgplot data=_test5;
vbar x / response=y ;
keylegend / position=topright noborder autoitemsize;
xaxis display=(nolabel);
yaxis grid;
inset 'text here' /border position=topright;
run;
```

For `position=`, it only provides serveral fixed options. But actually I know the ideal position for text is something like (400,380). Is there a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put the text at various places, you have a few options.  The simplest is an annotate dataset, where you specify where to put the text.  This is explained [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/65235/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1d3djir0t86nxn1l10ig8b2jbnl.htm).   example using your example dataset from the previous question:

```
data annods;
  input x1 y1 function $ drawspace :$10. label &:$9.;
datalines;
400 380 text WALLPIXEL Text Here  
;;;;
run;    

proc sgplot data=_test3 sganno=annods;
vbarparm category=Day response=DailySales/group=dow barwidth=0.7 nooutline;
series x=day y=WeeklySales;
keylegend / position=topright noborder autoitemsize;
xaxis display=(nolabel);
yaxis grid;
run;
```

If you're placing a lot of these, you can use the `scatterplot` with `markerchar` to place text as an overlaid scatterplot, or use the `text` plot available in 9.4 TS1M2.

I don't believe there's a way to make an exactly specified inset, though there may be a way to work around it playing with the various margins.  I suspect Sanjay (the lead developer, who often answers questions on communities.sas.com) is the right person to answer that specifically.